# Sorting dictionaries and lists from a file

Tags: python

I have to write to write a program that first reads in the name of an input file and then reads the input file using the file.readlines() method. The input file contains an unsorted list of number of seasons followed by the corresponding TV show. Then my program should put the contents of the input file into a dictionary where the number of seasons are the keys, and a list of TV shows are the values (since multiple shows could have the same number of seasons).

Then, I need to sort the dictionary by key (least to greatest) and output the results to a file named output_keys.txt, separating multiple TV shows associated with the same key with a semicolon (;). And finally, sort the dictionary by values (alphabetical order), and output the results to a file named output_titles.txt

```
 def readFile(filename):

   dict = {}

   with open(filename, 'r') as infile:

       lines = infile.readlines()

       for index in range(0, len(lines) - 1, 2):

           if lines[index].strip()=='':continue

           count = int(lines[index].strip())

           show = lines[index + 1].strip()

           if count in dict.keys():

               show_list = dict.get(count)

               show_list.append(show)

               show_list.sort()

           else:

               dict[count] = [show]

           print(count,show)

   return dict

def output_keys(dict, filename):

   with open(filename,'w+') as outfile:

       for key in sorted(dict.keys()):

           outfile.write('{}: {}\n'.format(key,'; '.join(dict.get(key))))

           print('{}: {}\n'.format(key,'; '.join(dict.get(key))))

def output_titles(dict, filename):

   titles = []

   for title in dict.values():

       titles.extend(title)

   with open(filename,'w+') as outfile:

       for title in sorted(titles):

           outfile.write('{}\n'.format(title))

           print(title)

def main():

   filename = input()

   dict = readFile(filename)

   if dict is None:

       print('Error: Invalid file name provided: {}'.format(filename))

       return


   output_filename_1 ='output_keys.txt'

   output_filename_2 ='output_titles.txt'

   output_keys(dict,output_filename_1)

   output_titles(dict,output_filename_2)

main()
```

I'm not sure why this code is giving me the error below when I try to run it.
[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This may be a better question for whomever wrote the test cases; it seems to be expecting some, but not all, of the output lines to be sorted in reverse alphabetical order, or even a random order based on the `expected output` you included

Comment: Also worth mentioning: Don't name your dictionary `dict`, as that shadows the built-in `dict` object and can cause problems

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
    def read_da_file(something):
        dict1 = {}
        with open(something, 'r') as infile:
            lines = infile.readlines()
            for index in range(0, len(lines) - 1, 2):
                if lines[index].strip() == '':
                    continue
                count = int(lines[index].strip())
                show = lines[index + 1].strip()
                if count in dict1.keys():
                    show_list = dict1.get(count)
                    show_list.append(show)
                else:
                    dict1[count] = [show]

        return dict1


    def output_keys(dict1, filename):
        with open(filename, 'w+') as q:
            for key in sorted(dict1.keys()):
                q.write('{}: {}\n'.format(key, '; '.join(dict1.get(key))))

                print('{}: {}'.format(key, '; '.join(dict1.get(key))))


    def output_titles(dict1, filename):
        titles = []

        for title in dict1.values():
            titles.extend(title)

        with open(filename, 'w+') as outfile:

            for title in sorted(titles):
                outfile.write('{}\n'.format(title))
                print(title)


    def main(x):
        file_name = x
        dict1 = read_da_file(file_name)
        if dict1 is None:
            print('Error: Invalid file name provided: {}'.format(file_name))

            return
        output_filename_1 = 'output_keys.txt'
        output_filename_2 = 'output_titles.txt'
        output_keys(dict1, output_filename_1)
        output_titles(dict1, output_filename_2)


    user_input = input()
    main(user_input)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 1):

remove the show_list.sort() in the function readfile. This is causing the sorting of the show names prior to it being needed for the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct code for any future inquiries. I'm currently taking IT-140 and this passed all tests. If you follow the pseudocode line for line in the module videos, you'll easily get this.

```
file_name = input()
user_file = open(str(file_name))
output_list = user_file.readlines()
my_dict = {}
show_list = []
show_list_split = []
for i in range(len(output_list)):
    temp_list = []
    list_object = output_list[i].strip('\n')
    if (i + 1 < len(output_list) and (i % 2 == 0)):
        if int(list_object) in my_dict:
            my_dict[int(list_object)].append(output_list[i + 1].strip('\n'))
        else:
            temp_list.append(output_list[i + 1].strip('\n'))
            my_dict[int(list_object)] = temp_list
            
my_dict_sorted_by_keys = dict(sorted(my_dict.items()))
for x in my_dict.keys():
    show_list.append(my_dict[x])
for x in show_list:
    for i in x:
        show_list_split.append(i)
show_list_split = sorted(show_list_split)
f = open('output_keys.txt', 'w')
for key, value in my_dict_sorted_by_keys.items():
    f.write(str(key) + ': ')
    for item in value[:-1]:
        f.write(item + '; ')
    else:
        f.write(value[-1])
        f.write('\n')
        
f.close()
f = open('output_titles.txt', 'w')
for item in show_list_split:
    f.write(item + '\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: this doesn't output anything for me

Comment: Sorry, I'm just now seeing this comment. Are you using Zybooks? Because this code passed all tests.

Answer (score 0):

```
def readInputFile(filename):
    shows_dict = {}
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    lines = file.readlines()
    for i in range(0, len(lines), 2):
        numOfSeasons = int(lines[i].strip())
        show = lines[i+1].strip()
        if numOfSeasons not in shows_dict.keys():
            shows_dict[numOfSeasons] = []
        shows_dict[numOfSeasons].append(show)
    return shows_dict


def outputSortedbyKeys(dict, filename):
    print("Sorting by keys: ")
    outfile = open(filename,'w')
    for key in sorted(dict.keys()):
        outfile.write('{}: {}\n'.format(key,'; '.join(dict.get(key))))
        print('{}: {}'.format(key,'; '.join(dict.get(key))))
    print(filename + " written successfully\n")


def outputSortedbyValues(dict, filename):
    print("Sorting by values: ")
    titles = []
    for key in dict.keys():
        for val in dict[key]:
            titles.append(val)
outfile = open(filename,'w')
for title in sorted(titles):
    outfile.write('{}\n'.format(title))
    print(title)
print(filename + " written successfully\n")

def main():
    filename = input("Enter the input filename: ") 
    shows_dict = readInputFile(filename)
    outputSortedbyKeys(shows_dict , 'output_keys.txt')
    outputSortedbyValues(shows_dict , 'output_titles.txt')

main()
```

Answer (score -2):

def readFile(filename):

```
dict = {}

with open(filename, 'r') as infile:

   lines = infile.readlines()

   for index in range(0, len(lines) - 1, 2):

        if lines[index].strip()=='':continue

        count = int(lines[index].strip())
        show = lines[index + 1].strip()
        
        if count in dict.keys():
           show_list = dict.get(count)
           show_list.append(show)
        
        else:
        
           dict[count] = [show]
        
        print(count)
        print(show)

return dict
```

def output_keys(dict, filename):

```
print()
with open(filename,'w+') as outfile:

   for key in sorted(dict.keys()):

       outfile.write('{}: {}\n'.format(key,'; '.join(dict.get(key))))

       print('{}: {}'.format(key,'; '.join(dict.get(key))))
print()
```

def output_titles(dict, filename):
titles = []

```
for title in dict.values():

   titles.extend(title)

with open(filename,'w+') as outfile:

   for title in sorted(titles):

       outfile.write('{}\n'.format(title))

       print(title)

print()
```

filename = input()
dict = readFile(filename)

if dict is None:
print('Error: Invalid file name provided: {}'.format(filename))

output1 ='output_keys.txt'
output2 ='output_titles.txt'
output_keys(dict,output1)
output_titles(dict,output2)

Answer (score -3):

def readFile(filename):

dict = {}

with open(filename, 'r') as infile:

```
   lines = infile.readlines()

   for index in range(0, len(lines) - 1, 2):

       if lines[index].strip()=='':continue

       count = int(lines[index].strip())

       name = lines[index + 1].strip()

       if count in dict.keys():

           name_list = dict.get(count)

           name_list.append(name)

       else:

           dict[count] = [name]

       print(count,name)
```

return dict

def output_keys(dict, filename):

with open(filename,'w+') as outfile:

```
   for key in sorted(dict.keys()):

       outfile.write('{}: {}\n'.format(key,'; ' .join(dict.get(key))))

       print('{}: {}\n'.format(key,'; ' .join(dict.get(key))))
```

def output_titles(dict, filename):

titles = []

for title in dict.values():

```
   titles.extend(title)
```

with open(filename,'w+') as outfile:

```
   for title in sorted(titles):

       outfile.write('{}\n'.format(title))

       print(title)
```

def main():

filename = input('Enter input file name: ')

dict = readFile(filename)

if dict is None:

```
   print('Error: Invalid file name provided: {}'.format(filename))

   return
```

print(dict)

output_filename_1 ='output_keys.txt'

output_filename_2 ='output_titles.txt'

output_keys(dict,output_filename_1)

output_titles(dict,output_filename_2 )

main()

This is the correct script