# Sorting with Lists and Dictionaries from a File

Tags: python, list, dictionary, file

Here's the prompt:
Write a program that first reads in the name of an input file and then reads the input file using the file.readlines() method. The input file contains an unsorted list of number of seasons followed by the corresponding TV show. Your program should put the contents of the input file into a dictionary where the number of seasons are the keys, and a list of TV shows are the values (since multiple shows could have the same number of seasons).

Sort the dictionary by key (least to greatest) and output the results to a file named output_keys.txt, separating multiple TV shows associated with the same key with a semicolon (;). Next, sort the dictionary by values (alphabetical order), and output the results to a file named output_titles.txt.

Ex: If the input is:

file1.txt and the contents of file1.txt are:

20

Gunsmoke

30

The Simpsons

10

Will & Grace

14

Dallas

20

Law & Order

12

Murder, She Wrote

the file output_keys.txt should contain:

10: Will & Grace

12: Murder, She Wrote

14: Dallas

20: Gunsmoke; Law & Order

30: The Simpsons

and the file output_titles.txt should contain:

Dallas

Gunsmoke

Law & Order

Murder, She Wrote

The Simpsons

Will & Grace

Here's what I have, but now the problem is that the keys aren't being sorted as integers.  So, any single digit channels aren't being sorted properly.  I've been running into string and integer and key errors as I've tried fixing this.  How can I fix the code to sort the TV show channels as integers?

```
file_name = input()
user_file = open(file_name)
output_list = user_file.readlines()

my_dict = {}

for index in range(len(output_list)):
    if index % 2 == 0:
        #if the line is even
        dict_keys = output_list[index].strip('\n')
        if dict_keys not in my_dict:
            my_dict[dict_keys] = []
    else:
        my_dict[dict_keys].append(output_list[index].strip('\n'))

f = open('output_keys.txt', 'w')
sorted_keys = sorted(my_dict.keys())
output_file = ''
tv_show_list = []
for the_key in sorted_keys:
    output_file += the_key + ': '
    for tvshow in my_dict[the_key]:
        output_file += tvshow + '; '
        tv_show_list.append(tvshow)
    output_file = output_file[:-2] + '\n'
f.write(output_file)
f.close()

f = open('output_titles.txt', 'w')
tv_show_list.sort()
sorted_list = ''
for tv_show in tv_show_list:
    sorted_list += tv_show + '\n'
f.write(sorted_list)
f.close()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting dictionaries and lists from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65208210/sorting-dictionaries-and-lists-from-a-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can convert the keys to integers before sorting them. Here's an updated version of your code that addresses this problem:

```
file_name = input()
user_file = open(file_name)
output_list = user_file.readlines()

my_dict = {}

for index in range(len(output_list)):
    if index % 2 == 0:
        # if the line is even
        dict_keys = int(output_list[index].strip('\n'))  # Convert to integer
        if dict_keys not in my_dict:
            my_dict[dict_keys] = []
    else:
        my_dict[dict_keys].append(output_list[index].strip('\n'))

f = open('output_keys.txt', 'w')
sorted_keys = sorted(my_dict.keys())
output_file = ''
tv_show_list = []
for the_key in sorted_keys:
    output_file += str(the_key) + ': '  # Convert back to string for output
    for tvshow in my_dict[the_key]:
        output_file += tvshow + '; '
        tv_show_list.append(tvshow)
    output_file = output_file[:-2] + '\n'
f.write(output_file)
f.close()

f = open('output_titles.txt', 'w')
tv_show_list.sort()
sorted_list = ''
for tv_show in tv_show_list:
    sorted_list += tv_show + '\n'
f.write(sorted_list)
f.close()
```

the keys are converted to integers using int(output_list[index].strip('\n')). When generating the output, str(the_key) is used to convert the keys back to strings for proper concatenation.